# How to add YES/NO checkbox column to existing table using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access

To begin with, I'm quite new to access.

I have a table , call it 'A'. I also have a form with a button which triggers an event when pushed. Using VBA I want to add a YES/NO column to 'A'.
I have accomplished that with the following code:

```
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "ALTER TABLE 'A' ADD COLUMN test YESNO;"
    
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
```

But it's just zeros on each row. I want to have the checkbox style. I know how to set it manually in "Display Control" but since I'm creating a "program" for a friend I want it to be set automatically when the button is pushed.

I have tried working around this problem for a while now and to be honest I don't even remember all the results I have gotten, all I know is that it's not what I want.
On different forums, with posts as old as 2003, I find some people recommending changing the "fld.CreateProperty..." to "fld.Append..." and vice versa. Not working for me.

The code following below is what I have tried but I get:

> "Run-time error '3421' Data type conversion error."

```
Set db = CurrentDb
Set td = db.TableDefs("A")
Set fld = td.Fields("test")
Set prp = fld.CreateProperty("DisplayControl", dbInteger, 106)

fld.Properties.Append prp
```

After some help in the comments my VBA code looks like this:

```
Private Sub Command13_Click()

    Dim strSQL  As String
    Dim dbs     As DAO.Database
    Dim tdf     As DAO.TableDef
    Dim fld     As DAO.Field
    Dim prp     As DAO.Property

    Set dbs = CurrentDb

    strSQL = "ALTER TABLE table ADD COLUMN test YESNO;"
    dbs.Execute strSQL

    Set tdf = dbs.TableDefs("table")
    Set fld = tdf.Fields("test")
    Set prp = fld.CreateProperty("DisplayControl", dbInteger, 106)
    fld.Properties.Append prp`
End Sub
```

When this code runs from a press of a button, I get the error
"Compile error: User-defined type not defined".
The debugger highlights the following yellow:

```
Private Sub Command13_Click()
```

and the following blue:

```
Dim dbs     As DAO.Database
```

Comment: Why do you need code to add a field? If you are routinely modifying table, likely structure is not adequately normalized. Why does it matter how field displays in table? Set whatever you want on form.

Comment: Once you have adapted the table and added the column, you are not going to do it again … not sure why you want the complexity of VBA?

Comment: You have to add another yes/no field every year? Sorry, still doesn't make sense to me. However, hope the supplied answer resolves issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your SQL syntax is not correct. Once corrected, this runs smoothly and as intended here:

```vb
Public Function SetFieldDisplay()

    Dim strSQL  As String
    Dim dbs     As DAO.Database
    Dim tdf     As DAO.TableDef
    Dim fld     As DAO.Field
    Dim prp     As DAO.Property

    Set dbs = CurrentDb

    strSQL = "ALTER TABLE TestTable ADD COLUMN DisplayTest YESNO;"
    dbs.Execute strSQL

    Set tdf = dbs.TableDefs("TestTable")
    Set fld = tdf.Fields("DisplayTest")
    Set prp = fld.CreateProperty("DisplayControl", dbInteger, 106)
    fld.Properties.Append prp

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Since I'm using VBA, is this code (including the 'public function' and 'end function') supposed to be inbetween the 'Private Sub Command_Click()' and 'End Sub'?
As I want this to occur when the button is pressed.

Comment: You can either call the function from the click event, or you can copy-paste the code lines into the click event.

Comment: I feel like I'm getting closer to the solution.
I copy paste the code (without the start and end function) and paste it between the Private sub opening and closing. I instead get "Compile error: User-defined type not defined". The sub opening is highlighted yellow and the Dim dbs is highlighted blue. I feel incredibly dumb...

Comment: Maybe you should append your code to your question.

Comment: More info now exists in the bottom of the question, thanks for hanging in there!

Comment: Go to menu _Tools, References_ and add a reference to: _Microsoft Office 16.0 Access database engine Object Library_.

Comment: THANK YOU, GUSTAV! You are fantastic, it works! Thank you, Thank you! But i can't help to wonder, what the actual problem was at last? why was it necessary to add the library thingy?

Comment: Probably you are also using _ADO_ which is quite different from _DAO_ and cannot use code like this for schema changes. Then you must use _ADOX_ which is very different story.